# How can I replace the deprecated set_magic_quotes_runtime in php?

Tags: php, deprecated

I'm getting this message when I try to run a php script I have to use but did not write.

```
Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webEchange/SiteWeb_V5/inc/fpdf.php on line 1810
```

Here is line 1810:

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
```

If this is a deprecated function, what can I replace it with?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Related [PHP 7.4 deprecated get_magic_quotes_gpc function alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260285/1839439)

Answer (score 72):

Check if it's on first.  That should get rid of the warning and it'll ensure that if your code is run on older versions of PHP that magic quotes are indeed off.

Don't just remove that line of code as suggested by others unless you can be 100% sure that the code will never be run on anything before PHP 5.3.

```
<?php
// Check if magic_quotes_runtime is active
if(get_magic_quotes_runtime())
{
    // Deactivate
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);
}
?>
```

`get_magic_quotes_runtime` is NOT deprecated in PHP 5.3.
Source: https://www.php.net/get_magic_quotes_runtime/

Comment: @stereofrog - are you sure? I haven't tested but the get function doesn't show that in the documentation, while the set function clearly does.

Comment: The get function always returns false in PHP > 5.4, but it is not yet deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately ```get_magic_quotes_runtime()``` is deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0 so this approach is no longer good.

Answer (score 33):

I used FPDF v. 1.53 and didn't want to upgrade because of possible side effects. I used the following code according to Yacoby:

Line 1164:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
    $mqr=get_magic_quotes_runtime();
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
}
```

Line 1203:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
    set_magic_quotes_runtime($mqr);
}
```

Comment: This is indeed the best solution. +1

Answer (score 15):

Since Magic Quotes is now off by default (and [removed in PHP v8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-runtime.php)), you can just remove that function call from your code.

Comment: see my answer on why this may not be a good idea ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217955/how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-set-magic-quotes-runtime-in-php/2218021#2218021 )

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to replace it with anything. The setting `magic_quotes_runtime` is [removed in PHP6](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) so the function call is unneeded. If you want to maintain backwards compatibility it may be wise to wrap it in a if statement checking [phpversion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) using [version_compare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Comment: And to back this with code: `if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);`

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade to version 1.6 of FPDF.

Comment: Note that **get**_magic_quotes_runtime was not removed until FPDF version 1.82

Answer (score 6):

In PHP 7 we can use:

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
```

instead of `set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);`

Answer (score 5):

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0)
```

I guess.

Comment: the magic_quotes_runtime option for ini_set is also Removed in PHP 6.0.0

Answer (score 5):

I fixed mine by removing that line of code
by commenting them out and it worked fine.

```
//if(get_magic_quotes_runtime())
//  @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
```

Comment: Me too i did the same

Comment: worked for me u are a star

Answer (score 3):

Just add the prefix "@" before the function to be @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
Not supported anymore in php 5.4, and don't remove or disable the function

Answer (score 2):

add these code into the top of your script to solve problem

```
@set_magic_quotes_runtime(false);
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
```

Comment: What are potential problems this can cause? The `@` sign suppresses errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just override them like:

```
if (!function_exists('set_magic_quotes_runtime')) {
    function set_magic_quotes_runtime($new_setting) {
        return true;
    }
}

if (!function_exists('split')) {
    function split($pattern, $string, $limit = -1) {
        return explode($pattern, $string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this function :

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
  set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
}
else {
  ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);
}
$magic_quotes = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
$file_buffer = fread($fd, filesize($path));
$file_buffer = $this->EncodeString($file_buffer, $encoding);
fclose($fd);
if ($magic_quotes) {
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
    set_magic_quotes_runtime($magic_quotes);
  }
  else {
    ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', $magic_quotes);
  }
}

return $file_buffer;
```