# mysqli_fetch_row() magic_quotes_runtime are deprecated since PHP 5.3

Tags: php, mysqli, row, fetch

I have just shifted the code from mysql to mysqli, following lines are selected from the code, it not a complete file. Tested the connection, its working fine. `"$totalRows"` this variable is showing a count, that means there is no problem with a query. But `"$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);"` line is making a trouble. When the execution comes to this point it throws an error message:

`"Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() [function.mysqli-fetch-row]: magic_quotes_runtime are deprecated since PHP 5.3"`

The same code was working fine while i was using mysql. I would be very thankful to get a quick reply.

```
$query = "SELECT -------
WHERE
product.productid =" . $productid;

$productid = mysqli_real_escape_string(linkDb(), $productid);

$result = mysqli_query(linkDb(), $query);               
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$DetailsHTML = "";

if ($totalRows > 0) {   
    $productid = mysqli_real_escape_string(linkDb(), $productid);       
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace the deprecated set\_magic\_quotes\_runtime in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217955/how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-set-magic-quotes-runtime-in-php)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php

Comment: Problem was not that big as i was thinking. I was digging into the technicalities of a code. What i did, just turned OFF a magic quotes run-time and everything got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (get_magic_quotes_runtime()) {
    $productid = stripslashes($productid); 
}

$productid = mysqli_real_escape_string(linkDb(), $productid);       
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Upgrade your php version to 5.4x or disable get_magic_quotes_runtime in your current version of php

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not that big as i was thinking. I was digging into the technicalities of a code. What i did, just turned OFF a magic quotes run-time and everything got fixed.