# PHP 7.4 deprecated get_magic_quotes_gpc function alternative

Tags: php, deprecated, php-7.4

I am encountered with the situation where one of my old code is using `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` which is deprecated in the latest **PHP version 7.4.***

Currently, I have something like this.

#### Add Slashes

```php
return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? addslashes($string) : $string;
```

#### Remove Slashes

```php
return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($string) : $string;
```

Which is obviously giving error

> Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated

**Question:**

How can I fix it? So can work the same without using `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` function?

Comment: Since PHP no longer adds slashes to request parameters ([removed in PHP 5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)), `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` **always** returns `false`. With that in mind, you don't have to do anything to your strings, they should always be clean.

Comment: I also can't think of any valid reasons to ever use `addslashes()`. I can't tell why you would have code like your first snippet, even prior to PHP 5.4

Comment: @Phil Do you mean PHP handle itself all such vulnerable injection?

Comment: No, quite the opposite. PHP now no longer gets in the way of developers and leaves securing your app up to you

Comment: I see, so could you please suggest me any way to secure it?

Comment: Secure what and against what vulnerabilities? Your question shows no uses of this code. If you were relying on this code to sanitise SQL query parameters, use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I see, got it. Thanks a lot @Phil I appreciate it.

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` together with `addslashes()` makes no sense.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need to remove every mention of this function from your code and do not replace it with anything else.

`get_magic_quotes_gpc()` has been useless ever since PHP 5.4.0. It would tell you whether you have magic quotes switched on in the configuration or not. Magic quotes were a terrible idea and this feature was removed for security reasons (PHP developers believed in magic & superstitions and wrote unsecure code).

Most likely even you yourself do not know why you had this line of code in your project. I know I was fooled by it when I was learning PHP. The reality is you do not need it at all. This function has nothing to do with security and the concept of input sanitization is preposterous.

Instead, rely on good security guidelines.

- Use parameterized prepared statements for interactions with the database. PHP has a very good library called PDO, which can be used with many DB drivers including MySQL.
- If you produce output, then escape **the output** taking into consideration the rules of that medium. For example when outputting to HTML use `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS.
- Never sanitize input. There is no magical solution that would protect you against everything. Instead, you as a developer must be aware of dangers and you need to know how to protect your code. [Don’t try to sanitize input. Escape output.](https://benhoyt.com/writings/dont-sanitize-do-escape/)

Comment: I disagree to your blanket statement that (all) input sanitation would be unecessary or even preposterous.
Instead you need to know what kind of input you can safely handle, and ensure that input matches that.
I do agree though that it's a misconception to think once it was sanitized once, it's safe for every further use.
FYI get_magic_quotes was a requirement for safe and sane code in the times when magic could just happen to your script. Prepared statements are better, but it should also still look nice, shouldn\'t it? ;)

Comment: @Zefiro Aren't you thinking of input validation? You validate the input you receive to make sure that it is what the application expects, but that has nothing to do with security.

Comment: You're right, I did. Though I don't really see a difference here. In case of magic quotes, it was "getting the input in a known state for further processing", i.e. you know whether escaping slashes had been added or not automagically.
(and in the times before Prepared Statements that was at least related to security)

Answer (score 13):

Replace [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) with `false`.

Then simplify complex expressions by removing the unreachable branches. E.g.

```
return get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? addslashes($string) : $string;
```

becomes simply

```
return $string;
```

Comment: thanks for the simple explanation of how to best deal with this deprecation.