# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc()

Tags: php

Error Message:
Fatal Error:Array
(
[type] => 1
[message] => Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.2-dev/I2CE/modules/Pages/lib/I2CE_Page.php:388
Stack trace:
#0 /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.2-dev/I2CE/modules/Pages/lib/I2CE_Page.php(315): I2CE_Page->setupGetPost()
#1 /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.2-dev/I2CE/modules/Pages/lib/I2CE_Wrangler.php(209): I2CE_Page->__construct()
#2 /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.2-dev/I2CE/modules/Pages/lib/I2CE_Wrangler.php(74): I2CE_Wrangler->getPage()
#3 /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.2-dev/ihris-manage/sites/Demo/pages/index.php(64): I2CE_Wrangler->wrangle()
#4 {main}
thrown
[file] => /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.2-dev/I2CE/modules/Pages/lib/I2CE_Page.php
[line] => 388
)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7.4 deprecated get\_magic\_quotes\_gpc function alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054418/php-7-4-deprecated-get-magic-quotes-gpc-function-alternative)

Comment: What's your question about this?

Answer (score 1):

Function get_magic_quotes_gpc is removed from PHP 8 (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php).
please update or merge your master files.
i hope it will be help