# function magic_quotes_gpc undefined

Tags: php, function, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

How can i fix this??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6J7s.png)

I tried changing the function but the get_magic_quotes_gpc() function is always red like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvYbH.png)

oh by the way, the problem shown in my vscode is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBXEG.png)

Comment: See [this info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP 7.4 deprecated get\_magic\_quotes\_gpc function alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054418/php-7-4-deprecated-get-magic-quotes-gpc-function-alternative)